# Pre-Calculus Help. If an arch is x tall and wide, will a plane 40m wide fly through it at 170m altitude?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The gateway arch in St. Louis is $162$ meters wide at the base and $185$ meters tall. Prove whether or not a plane that is $40$ meters wide can fly through at an altitude of $170$ meters?

I have started on this by making the equation of: $f(x) = a(x-h)^2 + k$ = vertex form I concluded that the vertex was: $81,185$. Half of the total width, and the height. $f(x) = a(x+81)^2 + 185$

I dont know if I am correct so far and I dont know where to go from here. Please help ASAP. Thanks

Comment: It's often easier to use the equation of a parabola through the origin, and adjust the coordinates of a point on the curve...

Comment: How would I go about creating a parabolic equation for this though?

Comment: There's only two;  memorize them.

Arms left or right: $y^2=Ax$ 

Arms up or down: $x^2=Ay$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the simplest formula for a parabola around the y-axis:$$x^2=Ay$$
With this formula, the vertex (the peak of the arch) is at $(0,0)$, the ground is at $y = -185$, and the legs hit the ground at $x=81$ and $x=-81$

So $(81,-185)$ lies on the parabola:
$$A=\frac{x^2}{y}=\frac{81^2}{-185}=-35.465$$So if the plane goes through the arch at $170$ meters above the ground, $y=-15$.  Calculate x, and see if the plane fits...

By the way, the St Louis Arch is not exactly a parabolic arch...

Comment: I solved for x and got: x = 23.06. So this means that the plane could Not fly through because the width is smaller than the plane? And thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Almost right, but the x is 23.06 m on each side of the center;  the plane is 20 m on each side...